# Error sudo apt-get install -f

Tags: updates, dpkg

```
(Reading database ... 152963 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg8:amd64 (8d-1+deb7u1) over (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.3.0-0ubuntu2  
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: and where is the question ?  which package do you want to install ?

Comment: @greenfrog I think OP is trying to install `libjpeg8` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to install the `libjpeg8` package but you already have another (probably old?) version of `libjpeg8` installed.

So you can either try removing the already installed version and re-install the newer one or make `dpkg` forcefully overwrite the confronting files by:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

Run `sudo apt-get install -f` to check everything is OK.